# AngularJS - How to creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an app using sailjs and angularjs, I've a problem on form when to try input a data to database. Here is my form 
[image]

If I'm input attibute a copy of the object or and array created and a fieldset attributes created on form sub attribute.

```
$scope.productcustom.templateAttribute =  angular.copy($scope.templateAttribute);
    _.each($scope.productcustom.variant, function (variant, index) {
        //variant.type = 'variant';
        variant.index = index;

        if (variant.attribute.length > 0) {
            _.each(variant.attribute, function (attribute, $index) {
                attribute.key = $scope.productcustom.templateAttribute[$index];
            })
        }
    })
```

and this my view

```
<div class="grid-100 form-group">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr ng-repeat="template in templateAttribute">
                        <td>{{template}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="button button-xs button-error button-labeled"
                            ng-click="removeItem( $index, templateAttribute )">
                                <span class="button-label"><i class="icon icon-minus-circled"></i></span>
                                delete
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control input-small" placeholder="attribute name" ng-model="attributeKey"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="button button-small button-default button-labeled"
                                ng-click="addItem(attributeKey, templateAttribute)">
                            <span class="button-label"><i class="icon icon-plus-circled"></i></span>
                            add
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

<div class="grid-100" ng-repeat="template in templateAttribute">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">{{template}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table" ng-repeat="variant in productcustom.variant">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>additional price</th>
                            <th colspan="2">file</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input class="form-control input-small" placeholder="name" ng-model="variant.attribute[$index].name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control input-small" placeholder="tambahan harga" ng-model="variant.attribute[$index].value" />
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2">
                                <button type="button" class="button button-small button-default button-labeled"
                                    ng-click="addItem( product.materials, material)">
                                <span class="button-label"><i class="icon icon-plus-circled"></i></span>
                                add
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <file-uploader 
                                    class="form-control"
                                    max-size="1000"
                                    allowed-extensions="png,jpeg,jpg"
                                    result-model="variant.attribute[$index].gallery"
                                    ng-required="true">
                                </file-uploader>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to input some sub attributes data not create. This is my partial code controller. So how to insert data like an above form ? please advance

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs:

## Usage

`angular.copy(source, [destination]);`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

So do this:
`angular.copy($scope.templateAttribute, $scope.productcustom.templateAttribute);`

Note, that Destination must be of the same type as source (so both are Arrays or both are Objects). If it's the case that they don't match up, you may have to copy to a new variable and continue the transformation with the new var.

Comment: @innonx please let me know if this helped